# Writing to a file makes random characters appear, why?

Tags: c, linux

NOTE: I'm working on linux (client/server) that's why i used strcpy.

I have a linked list with elements.

I've implemented a signup and signin form.

The signup function works fine, I'm saving every element of the list to the file.
Even the login function works fine, the main problem is:
After that login function, I'm calling `aggiornamento_file(...)` because I want to update some information after the login.
When that function is called, the file gets updated and I do get random characters at the end of the file.

What am I doing wrong?

```
void aggiornamento_file(struct utente *top){
    char username[MAX], password[MAX], gettoni[MAX], stato[MAX]="";
    int fd;
    int checking;

    fd = open("utenti.txt", O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(fd==-1){
        perror("ERROR apertura file utenti!");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        while(top!=NULL){
            strcpy(username, top->username);
            strcpy(password, top->password);
            sprintf(gettoni, "%d", top->gettoni);
            printf("gettoni %s\n", gettoni);
            strcpy(stato, top->stato);

            size_t us = strlen(username);
            write(fd, username, us);
            write(fd, "\t", 1);

            size_t pa = strlen(password);
            write(fd, password, pa);
            write(fd, "\t", 1);

            size_t ge = strlen(gettoni);
            write(fd, gettoni, ge);
            write(fd, "\t", 1);

            size_t st = strlen(stato);
            write(fd, stato, st); 
            write(fd, "\n", 1);

            top=top->next;
        }           

    }
    close(fd);
    return;

}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone for your time

Comment: TLDR: Are you taking care of the string terminating `'\0'` properly? Maybe you need `char whatever[MAX + 1] = {0};`

Comment: Why strcpy ? Why not just use `fprintf(fd, %s\t%s\t....)` you should have not initialized data somewhere, valgrind can help on that

Comment: Questions asking for debugging help need to provide complete minimal code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Did you look up the documentation on `open()`? You might need to use option `O_TRUNC` to delete the existing contents.

Comment: _" I'm working on linux (client/server) that's why i used strcpy"_ is non-sequitur.

Comment: Regardless of what the problem is it is dangerous code.  Change the `strcpy()` calls to `strncpy()` - e.g. `strncpy(username, top->usernamem sizeof(username) - 1);` and ensure that `username` etc are initialised thus:  `char username[MAX] = {0} ;`

Comment: The likelihood is that the _input_ strings are not terminated or that the final element of `top` is malformed and that the bug is elsewhere.  Nontheless the code presented is unsafe and needlessly complicated.  The copy to local strings serves no purpose, and the `strlen()`/`write()` sequence can be replaced with a single `fprintf()`.